# Authenticate using username and MD5 hash

Tags: authentication, passwords, md5

I need an application to authenticate an user. I have the username and the password. Logically, the username is plain text but the password is MD5. Do you know if I could develop a c# function to authenticate the user with this info, please?

Thanks in advance & Cheers.

David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hash the MD5 password and compare this to the given one.

**NOTE:** MD5 isn't save anymore, it can be cracked. Use SHA* version instead.